# Display whatsapp messages in order -- twilio whatsapp api

Tags: twilio, botframework, whatsapp

I am using **ms bot frame work** for creating chatbot. For whatsapp i have used **twilio whatsapp api** with ms **direct line** channel.

Everything is working fine but the messages are not displaying in sequence.

Comment: Are you using C# or Javascript for your bot? Since there is a [community adapter for Twilio WhatsApp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@botbuildercommunity/adapter-twilio-whatsapp) available for JS. This adapter supports all features on Twilio WhatsApp and maps them directly to the Bot Framework SDK.

Comment: I am using C#, I am able to send messages(multiple at a time) but the problem is its 
 displaying in random order (https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223134247-Can-my-SMS-messages-arrive-in-order-  --- similar in sms service)

Comment: How are you sending the messages? Are you using multiple context.sendActivity() calls or are you using context.sendActivities() to send them in bulk. My experience is that the latter works better combined with the Twilio WhatsApp API, I don't have many issues with the message order.

Comment: When i send below message to twilio its not displaying in order                                     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Response>
  <Message>Welcome to the user</Message>
  <Message>
To get started please select any option below or Type 'login' to sign-in, Type 'logout' to sign-out,Type 'help' to view this message again, Type 'menu' to view service options.
<Body>
Website -- https://www.website.com
</Body>
</Message>
  <Message>Please choose an option from the list</Message>
  <Message>Help
 My Profile
Logout
</Message>
</Response>

Comment: I have **solved** this issue by sending one message at a time and finding status of current message to send next message.